# What are good sources for virus signature data?

Tags: web-services, antivirus, virus-scanning, virus-definitions

Is there any website which provides antivirus definition database to help make new antivirus software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ClamWin](http://www.clamwin.com/) is a free, open-source antivirus software. You might find something useful there.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried looking into [ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net)? Open source AV program, can be linked to via API, and you should be able to get the database for it, but I'm not sure how offhand.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few CSV files that contain a large (but not even close to commercial companies) virus signature definitions. Bellow there are in total between 2-4k definitions.

http://files.codes-sources.com/fichier_fullscreen.aspx?id=21418&f=virussignatures.txt&lang=en

and here

http://www.nlnetlabs.nl/downloads/antivirus/antivirus/virussignatures.strings

Hope it helps!